Controlling size of image intervals from the derivative
I am trying to understand the proof of van der Corput's inequality on exponential sums. Basically, we assume that we have a twice continuously derivable function $f$ on a bounded interval $I$ such that
$$\lambda \leq f' \leq \alpha \lambda$$
for an $\alpha \geq 1$.
Let a $0 < \delta < 1/2$. It is claimed that

$I$ can be split into less than $\alpha \lambda |I|+ 2$ intervals on which $\|f\| \geq \delta$ (where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the distance to the nearest integer)
$I$ can be split into less than $\alpha \lambda |I|+1$ other intervals, each of length less than $2\delta / \lambda$

Even if I do understand the spirit of the argument (that the constraints on $f'$ implies that $f$ cannot cover more than $\alpha \lambda |I|$), how can I write it properly? (and how to precisely justify the $+1$ and $+2$ appearing in the statements?)
